# Can not pipe the output of echo command to ls

Tags: bash

everyone, i found this strange problem ( maybe it is a feature ) this afternoon.
In my current working directory, there are 5 files, namely a,b,c,d,e

If i issue the following command

```
echo "a" | ls -l
```

What I expect is only the detailed information of file a is listed.
But from the output, the detailed information of file a,b,c,d,e are listed.
It seems as if the command before the pipe is not working, eg, the following command will output exactly as if only `ls -l` is executed.

```
echo "whatever_you_type" | ls -l
```

I am confused, can anybody help to explain this issue?
I know i can workaround this problem by using `xargs`, something like `echo "a" | xargs ls -l`
But I want to know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you pipe something into another process, it will be pushed into its `STDIN` stream. As ls does not read from stdin, it just ignores that. What you want is that the parameters are passed to the command line of `ls`. This can be achieved by using something like this:

```
my_file="a"
ls -l "$my_file"
```

Alternatively, you can use [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) which can be used to construct command line parameters from stdin input. In your case, you could use it like

```
echo "a" | xargs ls -l
```

It will execute an `ls -l [filename]` for each space-separated string of stdin input.

Answer (score 3):

`ls` doesn't take input from `stdin`. `xargs` works because it invokes `ls` one or more times with arguments assembled from its input.
An alternative way of achieving your example would be:

`ls -l $(echo "a")`

Just make sure you haven't got any filenames with spaces in.

Comment: I feel more comfortable with the second solution you offered. Seems more "natural" to me. I never use xargs because there is always a way to get the information you want "in" the command line.

Comment: Two remarks: (1) in this case, the subshell is unnecessary. Just use the variable. (2) If there is the slightest chance that you have spaces or special chars in your filename (read as "always"), you should quote the output like `ls -l "$(echo "a")"`. Generally, you can't have too few quotes around arguments in shell scripting.

Comment: @Holger - I agree that in the trivial case the subshell is unnecessary, but I was assuming OP had a more complicated scenario in mind.